# sharpssh didn't put files

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

I have next problem: when i try to copy files on SFTP server, nothing happens. I didnt get any error or exception, just nothing
listing here:

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Tamir.SharpSsh;
using Tamir.Streams;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string strHost = "[host]";
    string strUserName = "[username]";
    int nPort = 22;
    string strPwd = "[pass]";
    SshTransferProtocolBase sshCp;
    sshCp = new Sftp(strHost, strUserName);

    sshCp.Password = strPwd;

    Console.Write("Connecting...");
    try
    {
      sshCp.Connect(nPort);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Can't connect: " + strHost + e);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    sshCp.Connect(nPort);
    try
    {
      while (true)
      {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\myruswclf\\SQL Folder\\Common Files\\RAE_Dialer");

        foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
          sshCp.Put(file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name, "\\opt\\avaya\\pds\\xfer\\public\\public\\");
          Console.WriteLine("File " + file.Name + " moved to diler");
        }

        foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
          System.IO.File.Copy(file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name, "\\\\myruswclf\\SQL Folder\\Common Files\\Archive_RAE_Dialer\\" + file.Name, true);
          String mydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm");
          // Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
          System.IO.File.Move("\\\\myruswclf\\SQL Folder\\Common Files\\Archive_RAE_Dialer\\" + file.Name, "\\\\myruswclf\\SQL Folder\\Common Files\\Archive_RAE_Dialer\\" + file.Name.Split('.')[0] + "_" + mydate + '.' + file.Name.Split('.')[1]);
          Console.WriteLine("File " + file.Name.Split('.')[0] + "_" + mydate + '.' + file.Name.Split('.')[1] + " moved to archive");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 300000ms ...");
        Thread.Sleep(300000);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("woops! Error " + strHost + e);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

But, when i try do this on another sftp server(local) it's work
Where can be mistake? what i doing wrong? Please, help me :-)

Comment: you don't have rights on the other server.

Comment: you also are running `sshCp.Connect(nPort);` twice, once in the try and once outside.

Comment: Hagan, thanks! But i have premissions when trying do this actions with WinSCP. is it possible?

Comment: No, System.IO.File.Copy works currect. Didnt work sshCp.Put command.

Comment: I suggest a debugger -- I also see you are connecting twice.  This is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I fix this mistake and programm still didnt work.

Comment: And i cant use debugger on PC which had potential to connect to Sftp server :-\

Comment: But you can connect to that server with WinSCP?  Interesting security setup -- are you sure the PC which you are trying to run it on isn't firewalled?

Comment: Ye, banking security system :-\  Yes, im sure, it isnt firewalled